# Android only displays my 1st database search

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio

I'm trying to create an app that takes some values from a database. 
 The value I am looking for in the database has multiple
 entries, but in Android it only displays the 1st one it finds. I  presume i just need 1/2 lines, but I have no clue what&where.

```
private void getData() {
     String qrcode = textView1.getText().toString().trim();
     if (qrcode.equals("")) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       return;
     }
     loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

     String url = Config.DATA_URL+textView1.getText().toString().trim();

     StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(String response) {
         loading.dismiss();
         showJSON(response);
       }
     },
         new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     });

     RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
     requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
 }

 private void showJSON(String response){
     String title="";
     String image = "";
     try {
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
       JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
       JSONObject androidData = result.getJSONObject(0);
       title = androidData.getString(Config.KEY_TITLE);
       image = androidData.getString(Config.KEY_IMAGE);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
     textViewResult.setText("Title:\t" + title);//+"\nImagine :\t"+ image);
     Picasso.with(this).load("http://192.168.1.254/2015/380panel/uploads/images/sm/" + image).into(ImageView1);

 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     getData();
 }
```

Comment: You are taking only the first result in the json array: JSONObject androidData = result.getJSONObject(0);
>                 title = androidData.getString(Config.KEY_TITLE);
>                 image = androidData.getString(Config.KEY_IMAGE);

Comment: I just need to modify the 0 with another int?

Comment: *I just need to modify the 0 with another int?* then you would still have one ... but not the first one - or an error if there is only one row ... you have to learn programming's basics concepts like loops ... *but I have no clue what&where* - SO is not a good place for learning programming ...

Comment: Isn't this a forum for asking programming related questions? I didn't ask for someone to write my code, I just didn't know what to do ;) @Selvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are taking only the first result of the response :

```
JSONObject androidData = result.getJSONObject(0);
title = androidData.getString(Config.KEY_TITLE);
image = androidData.getString(Config.KEY_IMAGE);
```

And you are populating only ONE textview:

```
textViewResult.setText("Title:\t" + title);//+"\nImagine :\t"+ image);
```

You need to iterate/loop for each json object received in the jsonArray and populate a list of textview if you want to see all the results!

Loop array : [Android JSONArray looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845734/android-jsonarray-looping)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still have no clue what I should modify

Comment: Did you understand why you need to loop the JSONArray?